# Função para formatar datas

Tags: javascript, data

Tenho uma duvida em relação ao JavaScript .

Quero criar uma função onde receba uma data e depois a consiga mostrar como quiser. por exemplo AAAA/MM/DD ou DD/MM/AAAA ou outra forma qualquer.

tenho a função que tem uma data:

```
function data (){
  Var dt= 20-05-2015;
```

Comment: [Momentjs](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o [JavaScript Date Format](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) para isso.

```js
 /*
     * Date Format 1.2.3
     * (c) 2007-2009 Steven Levithan <stevenlevithan.com>
     * MIT license
     *
     * Includes enhancements by Scott Trenda <scott.trenda.net>
     * and Kris Kowal <cixar.com/~kris.kowal/>
     *
     * Accepts a date, a mask, or a date and a mask.
     * Returns a formatted version of the given date.
     * The date defaults to the current date/time.
     * The mask defaults to dateFormat.masks.default.
     */

    var dateFormat = function () {
        var    token = /d{1,4}|m{1,4}|yy(?:yy)?|([HhMsTt])\1?|[LloSZ]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'/g,
            timezone = /\b(?:[PMCEA][SDP]T|(?:Pacific|Mountain|Central|Eastern|Atlantic) (?:Standard|Daylight|Prevailing) Time|(?:GMT|UTC)(?:[-+]\d{4})?)\b/g,
            timezoneClip = /[^-+\dA-Z]/g,
            pad = function (val, len) {
                val = String(val);
                len = len || 2;
                while (val.length < len) val = "0" + val;
                return val;
            };
    
        // Regexes and supporting functions are cached through closure
        return function (date, mask, utc) {
            var dF = dateFormat;
    
            // You can't provide utc if you skip other args (use the "UTC:" mask prefix)
            if (arguments.length == 1 && Object.prototype.toString.call(date) == "[object String]" && !/\d/.test(date)) {
                mask = date;
                date = undefined;
            }
    
            // Passing date through Date applies Date.parse, if necessary
            date = date ? new Date(date) : new Date;
            if (isNaN(date)) throw SyntaxError("invalid date");
    
            mask = String(dF.masks[mask] || mask || dF.masks["default"]);
    
            // Allow setting the utc argument via the mask
            if (mask.slice(0, 4) == "UTC:") {
                mask = mask.slice(4);
                utc = true;
            }
    
            var    _ = utc ? "getUTC" : "get",
                d = date[_ + "Date"](),
                D = date[_ + "Day"](),
                m = date[_ + "Month"](),
                y = date[_ + "FullYear"](),
                H = date[_ + "Hours"](),
                M = date[_ + "Minutes"](),
                s = date[_ + "Seconds"](),
                L = date[_ + "Milliseconds"](),
                o = utc ? 0 : date.getTimezoneOffset(),
                flags = {
                    d:    d,
                    dd:   pad(d),
                    ddd:  dF.i18n.dayNames[D],
                    dddd: dF.i18n.dayNames[D + 7],
                    m:    m + 1,
                    mm:   pad(m + 1),
                    mmm:  dF.i18n.monthNames[m],
                    mmmm: dF.i18n.monthNames[m + 12],
                    yy:   String(y).slice(2),
                    yyyy: y,
                    h:    H % 12 || 12,
                    hh:   pad(H % 12 || 12),
                    H:    H,
                    HH:   pad(H),
                    M:    M,
                    MM:   pad(M),
                    s:    s,
                    ss:   pad(s),
                    l:    pad(L, 3),
                    L:    pad(L > 99 ? Math.round(L / 10) : L),
                    t:    H < 12 ? "a"  : "p",
                    tt:   H < 12 ? "am" : "pm",
                    T:    H < 12 ? "A"  : "P",
                    TT:   H < 12 ? "AM" : "PM",
                    Z:    utc ? "UTC" : (String(date).match(timezone) || [""]).pop().replace(timezoneClip, ""),
                    o:    (o > 0 ? "-" : "+") + pad(Math.floor(Math.abs(o) / 60) * 100 + Math.abs(o) % 60, 4),
                    S:    ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"][d % 10 > 3 ? 0 : (d % 100 - d % 10 != 10) * d % 10]
                };
    
            return mask.replace(token, function ($0) {
                return $0 in flags ? flags[$0] : $0.slice(1, $0.length - 1);
            });
        };
    }();
    
    // Some common format strings
    dateFormat.masks = {
        "default":      "ddd mmm dd yyyy HH:MM:ss",
        shortDate:      "m/d/yy",
        mediumDate:     "mmm d, yyyy",
        longDate:       "mmmm d, yyyy",
        fullDate:       "dddd, mmmm d, yyyy",
        shortTime:      "h:MM TT",
        mediumTime:     "h:MM:ss TT",
        longTime:       "h:MM:ss TT Z",
        isoDate:        "yyyy-mm-dd",
        isoTime:        "HH:MM:ss",
        isoDateTime:    "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss",
        isoUtcDateTime: "UTC:yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss'Z'"
    };
    
    // Internationalization strings
    dateFormat.i18n = {
        dayNames: [
            "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat",
            "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
        ],
        monthNames: [
            "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec",
            "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
        ]
    };
    
    // For convenience...
    Date.prototype.format = function (mask, utc) {
        return dateFormat(this, mask, utc);
    };





today = new Date();
var dateString = today.format("dd/MM/yyyy"); //Passo o formato da data aqui
alert(dateString);
```

[Fonte.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3552496/4843158)

Answer (score 2):

Crie uma função JS:

```
function formatarData(data) {
    var d = new Date(data),
        mes = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        dia = '' + d.getDate(),
        ano = d.getFullYear();

    if (mes.length < 2) mes = '0' + mes;
    if (dia.length < 2) dia = '0' + dia;

    return [dia, mes, ano].join('/'); // "join" é o caracter para separar a formatação da data, neste caso, a barra (/)
}
```

Uso:

```
alert(formatarData('Tue Jun 23,2015'));
```

Resultado:

```
23/06/2015
```

Outros exemplos:

```
alert(formatarData('12/23/2015')); // Resultado 23/12/2015
alert(formatarData('01/01/2015')); // Resultado 01/01/2015
```

Se quiser mudar o retorno da função, basta alterar para a ordem desejada:

```
return [dia, mes, ano].join('/'); // Caso queira dd/mm/aaaa
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nf3hyq81/)

Answer (score 2):

Em [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), ficaria assim:

```
var data_formatada = moment(dt, "DD-MM-YYYY").format("DD/MM/YYYY");
```